# Does "Thanks a Lot" sound too casual for showing gratitude to someone in a higher position

Tags: word-choice

I'm thinking probably... because of "a lot"

Comment: @A good formal choice, which sounds particularly home-counties English, is "Thank you so much."

Comment: LOL clever ....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not only does it sound informal, but both *Thanks!* and *Thanks a lot!* are frequently used ironically - frequently enough that they should be avoided anytime there's even a slight chance of ambiguity.  I would never use "thanks a lot" to my boss or supervisor unless we also happened to be friends.

It would be hard to go wrong with **Thank you**, **Thank you very much**, or **Many thanks**.

Comment: Yes, if you use "Thanks a lot" you have to be ***very*** careful of your tone of voice. Otherwise it sounds sarcastic. It's simply not worth the risk. Even worse are, "Thanks a bunch" and "Thanks a heap".  Both of those are pure sarcasm.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, it will probably sound a bit too casual, if you are addressing someone in a higher position.
Not unless the person who is in a higher position doesn't mind, or you and that person are in close standing. Otherwise, I would say:

> Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Depends what you mean by "higher": if it's somebody you'd still be on fairly informal terms with (e.g. first name terms, or non-honorific terms if your native language has such a thing), then "thanks a lot" is fine. If the context demands use of more formal language, or if you're in doubt, then you can't go too wrong with "thank you very much".